# Finding the smallest field containing multivariate polynomial evaluations of the roots of an irreducible polynomial

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, algebraic-numbers

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}$Suppose I have an irreducible polynomial $f\in\Q[x]$ and suppose I know the roots say $r_1,\dots,r_n\in \bar \Q$. I want to know if there is an easy way to "compute" the smallest number field $K$ such that we have 
$$a_0(r_1,\dots, r_n) + a_1(r_1,\dots, r_n)x + \dots + a_k(r_1,\dots, r_n)x^k \in K[x]$$
where $a_0,\dots, a_k \in \Q[x_1,\dots, x_n]$. I am actually only interested in knowing $[K:\Q]$.

I suppose this is "strongly" dependent on how $a_0,\dots, a_k$ are constructed. In my particular case, I want to prove that $[K:\Q]$ is actually always even. I guess I can go into details of the $a_i's$ but I am not sure if this will help in solving $[K:\Q]$. For me, the multivariate polynomials $a_0,\dots,a_k$ are not symmetric but they are certainly not random (i.e. there are non-trivial permutations of the $n$-indeterminates that preserve the $a_i$'s). I do not know if any of these information helps.

Even a specific example that could give me a start on how to solve this kind of problem is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want this to work for any $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, \cdots x_n]$ or just for specific ones?

Comment: I have specific ones in mind. For any $a_i$ will lead to $K$ being the splitting field of $f$.